# generating ics file programmatically but never able to produce what timezone invitation was produced

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exchange-server, icalendar, invite, meeting-request

Hi I was trying send meeting invites through my asp.net MVC application. There was a requirement to show which timezone this invite was created as in following image. I tried various things as told by Microsoft support, neither of them worked.

[image: Meeting Invite]

As per Microsoft Exchange Server support's advice I created following.

```
TZID:Sri Jayawardenepura
BEGIN:STANDARD 
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Sri Jayawardenepura:20140416T033000Z
DTSTAMP:20140327T113138Z
DTEND;TZID=Sri Jayawardenepura:20140416T060000Z 
LOCATION: Board room
```

After adding TZID inside DTSTART, it is not coming as invite to gmail.

but following works fine as invitation both in outlook configured with Exchange Server and webmails like gmail.

```
 TZID:Sri Jayawardenepura
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20140318T033000Z
DTSTAMP:20140327T122640Z
DTEND:20140318T060000Z
LOCATION: Board room
```

however that requirement of showing timezone where invite was created not fulfilled yet. 
Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/dateTime.html it states that `UTC time is identified by a Z suffix character` as well as  `The TZID property parameter MUST NOT be applied to DATE-TIME properties whose time values are specified in UTC.`

I would suspect that if you are using a timezone identifier that you need to remove the Z from the end of the date to get it to work properly.

EDIT: So, I was having troubles with timezones before as well, so I had only used UTC time, however I just got one to work with a timezone, so I hope this helps. Inside VTIMEZONE, you have a STANDARD, but you do not have a DTSTART inside the STANDARD. Again, quoting from the above link, `The standard or daylight component MUST include the "DTSTART", "TZOFFSETFROM" and "TZOFFSETTO" properties.`

Comment: when I remove the Z, it does not change the time accordingly when the recipient is in the different timezone. Anyhow thanks for the reply josh

Answer (score 0):

It is not RFC5545 compliant but many calendars will expect a TZID to be compatible with the Olson DB and also may expect to have the calendar property `X-WR-TIMEZONE` set.

What I have seen is that when doing all of above you increase your calendar compatibility ratio.